# Is there public transportation from Central Shiraz to Persepolis?

Tags: budget, public-transport, iran

I know there are many tours and everybody in town with a car is willing to drive you there, but I would rather take public transport.

Does anybody know whether this is possible and how to do it? Of course I have to get back to the city as well.

Comment: Walking or hitch-hiking are of course the cheapest options.

Comment: I have updated your question to not be a price-shopping question (which is off-topic)... And to avoid silly answers like "walking"... I hope you don't object.

Comment: just wondering- why are you so interested in public transit between these two spots?

Comment: @DanS - 1. The price, 2. I have a general rule to not use taxis when I travel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are buses, but information on them varies.

[Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/iran/central-iran/persepolis-takht-e-jamshid/transport/getting-there-away) suggests a shuttle bus is needed for the last 12km:

> It’s not difficult to get to Persepolis by a combination of bus and
>   local taxi from Shiraz. Take a minibus (IR4000, 42km, hourly) or
>   savari (IR8000, or IR40, 000 for the whole car to Persepolis) from the
>   southern edge of Carandish Terminal to Marvdasht, where they stop at
>   Basij Sq. From here you should be able to find a shuttle taxi (IR3000,
>   12km) to Persepolis.

[Another site](http://www.iranbudgettour.com/visit-takht-e-jamshid-persepolis-iran-historical-attractions) suggests you can get a bus directly there.  I'd suggest confirming that at the bus terminal though since it seems a little less authorative.

> Getting to Persepolis: By Bus from Shiraz: Go by bus to visit
>   Persepolis for easiest travel, take regular and frequently run Buses
>   from Karandish Bus Terminal in Shiraz; you'll ride in a bus for 45
>   Minutes.